# How to query based on requirements?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I am creating an app where people can schedule appointments with professionals.
When the professionals are creating an account, sometimes the service they want to offer may require a work permit/license in certain locations.

I've been trying to create a database design on Firebase Firestore where based on the location, and type of service, I can get a list of requirements (e.g. work permit or insurance).

It's also worth noting that not all services are available in all locations.

So far the design I have is the following (those in brackets are collections):

```
(locations)
    United States
        (cities)
            New York
                (categories)
                    Home Improvement
                        (services)
                            House Cleaning
                            - array of licenses/permits required
```

The user's country and city are already known and stored in the user's profile document.

I am pretty new to all of this but even I can see that this is very repetitive as I'd have to do the same thing for every single location.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single collection "services" with documents containing every detail about a service should do it.

```js
services -> {serviceID}
```

A document of a service may look something like:

```js
{
  serviceID: "service1234",
  category: "Home Improvement",
  location: "United States",
  city: "New York",
  requiredPermits: []
}
```

Now you can easily query services based on location, category or any other field:

```js
const servicesCol = firebase.firestore().collection("services") 
const servicesInNYC = await servicesCol.where("city", "==", "New York").get()

// for fetching services in multiple cities
await servicesCol.where("city", "in", ["New York", "Washington DC"]).get()
```

Additionally, if a service can have multiple categories then you can store an array of categories in their documents and then fetch a specific category like this:

```js
await servicesCol.where("categories", "array-contains", "Home Improvement")
```

Similarly you can query for services that require a specific license/permit (make sure you have those in an array in the document).

**Edit:** If a single service can have have multiple locations with different permits required then you can remove `requiredPermits` field and move location to a sub-collection as follows:

```
services -> {serviceID} -> locations -> {locationID}
```

Each document in locations sub-collection may look like:

```js
{
  country: "United States",
  city: "New York",
  permits: [....]
}
```

Now you can query locations of a service with a specific permit:

```js
const serviceLocations = await servicesCol.doc("serviceID").collection("locations").where("permits", "array-contains", "permit1ID").get()

// To get services with a specific location/permit
const locationsGroup = firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("locations")
const snap = await locationsGroup.where("permits", "array-contains", "permit1ID").get()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Everything seems to be fine except that the service may have different license/permit requirements in different countries

Comment: @devOP1 you might have to move locations in a sub-collection as explained in the updated answer then.

Comment: How would I query for all the services in a specific country after i've moved the locations to a subcollection?

Comment: @devOP1 you can still use collectionGroup query with country and then use DocumentReferences of those docs to get the parent document i.e. the service doc.

Comment: No I don't sorry. Could you please add an example of how I can query all the services in a specific country?

Comment: I'll try to add that query asap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235353/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-devop1).